# ReactTransitionGroup doesn't works with React-redux connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on a bigger project but I created this short example to illustrate the problem.

If I use `Box` component, its works. It outputs in the console `componentWillEnter` and 
`componentWillLeave` when we click on the button.

If I use `BoxContainer` container, it doesn't work anymore. `componentWillEnter` and `componentWillLeave` special lifecycle hooks are not called.

```js
{this.state.shouldShowBox && <BoxContainer/>}
```

Webpack build is done correctly, no errors in the console, but It outputs nothing.

I also tried with high-level API :`ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, and it works with `Box` and `BoxContainer` component. But I need to use the low-level API : `ReactTransitionGroup`.

Do you have an idea why it doesn't works when we use `react-redux`?

### Version used :

- react : **15.0.2**
- redux : **3.5.2**
- react-redux : **4.4.5**

### Code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, compose, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import TransitionGroup from 'react/lib/ReactTransitionGroup';

// Box component
class Box extends React.Component {
  componentWillEnter(callback) {
    console.log('componentWillEnter');
    callback();
  }

  componentWillLeave(callback) {
    console.log('componentWillLeave');
    callback();
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="box"/>;
  }
}

// Boxe connected component
const BoxContainer = connect(null, {})(Box);

// App component
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    shouldShowBox: true
  };

  toggleBox = () => {
    this.setState({
      shouldShowBox: !this.state.shouldShowBox
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TransitionGroup>
          {this.state.shouldShowBox && <BoxContainer/>}
        </TransitionGroup>
        <button className="toggle-btn" onClick={this.toggleBox}>
          toggle
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// reducer
function reducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// store
const store = createStore(reducer);

// render
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not supposed to work because connect wraps your component into a "connected" object, however, there are some workarounds like [connect-with-transition-group](https://github.com/esayemm/connect-with-transition-group)

The creator of Redux, Dan Abramov, has said this about the [issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/303)

> To be completely honest I don’t want to hardcode supports for
>   transition groups into connect(). This is a very specific API that is
>   not going to be the React animation API and acts more like an escape
>   hatch until there are better solutions. The way it invokes instance
>   methods on a nested instance does not align with React conceptual
>   model very well.
>
> I would suggest you to:
>
> - Either write your own wrapper around connect() like you suggested
> - Or use a more React-friendly approach to animations such as https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion
>
> Either write your own wrapper around connect() like you suggested Or
>   use a more React-friendly approach to animations such as
>   https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion

Answer (score 1):

We also tried to do the same thing, hooking up `TransitionGroup` with `redux` connected component, like

```
<TransitionGroup>
  layerIds.map(id => ( <Layer ...>))
</TransitionGroup>
```

where `Layer` itself is a connected redux component.

We also tried wrap `Layer` ourselves like

```
const WrappedLayer = (props) =>{
  return <TransitionGroup>
  <Layer {...props}/>
  </TransitionGroup>
}
```

And connect it using `WrappedLayer`, it will only work on mounting stage like `componentWillAppear` and `componentDidAppear`, will not work on unmounting stage, since when you delete a layer on UI, the `TransitionGroup` is also deleted, then life cycle method like `componentWillLeave` will never be triggered.

Good news is that we finally find a very handy library `react-move` https://github.com/react-tools/react-move , which we think is better than `react-motion`, since we can custom the duration, the animation curve, and it is very clean.

Hopefully, this will help you, if you meet any problem by using `react-move`, just msg me.