# Problem with correctly rendering component with React-Transition-Group and Redux

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux

I'm currently building my first app with React and today I encountered a problem I think I cannot resolve on my own yet.

So what's the matter:

I'm rendering a Result.js container, which consists of smaller components displaying data from the API. Initially, it is hidden (not rendered) and it gets rendered after passing query into Search component and receiving a response. I'm trying to implement a transition so it fades in (opacity 0 -> 1) after response. This is working fine, but also I want it to fade out when the user sends another request and fades in again. This is what's not working, or working parts. Right now the fade-out animation plays out, but right near the end, there is a flash of an earlier state of the component with previous data. Like there was an additional render in there. I tried different approaches like with inline styling (display: none) but most of them ended with fade-out animation not playing at all.

I'm using Redux to store API response and components' display property. 
The code I've been working on can be found below. I'll be very thankful for any suggestions or insights, also related to my coding style/code 'cleanness' :) Thank you!

Result.js container:

```
const Result = props => {
   return (
      <Transition
         in={props.displayResult}
         timeout={1000}
         mountOnEnter
         unmountOnExit
      >
         {state => (
            <div
               className={`${classes.Box} ${
                  state === 'entering'
                     ? classes.ResultOpen
                     : state === 'entered'
                     ? classes.ResultVisible
                     : state === 'exiting'
                     ? classes.ResultClosed
                     : state === 'exited'
                     ? classes.ResultVisible
                     : null
               }`}
            >
               <div className={classes.BoxRow}>
                  <Sprites />
                  <NameId />
               </div>
               <div className={classes.BoxRow}>
                  <div className={classes.BoxColumn}>
                     <Abilities />
                     <Metrics />
                  </div>
                  <Types />
               </div>
               <div className={classes.BoxRow}>
                  <Stats />
               </div>
            </div>
         )}
      </Transition>
   );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      displayResult: state.result.displayResult
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(React.memo(Result));
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
   id: null,
   name: '',
   spriteFront: '',
   spriteBack: '',
   types: [],
   height: null,
   weight: null,
   stats: [],
   baseExperience: null,
   abilities: [],
   moves: [],
   displayResult: false,
   error: false,
   loading: false
};

const setResult = (state, action) => {
   return updateObject(state, {
      id: action.result.id,
      name: action.result.name,
      spriteFront: action.result.sprites.front_default,
      spriteBack: action.result.sprites.back_default,
      types: action.result.types,
      height: action.result.height,
      weight: action.result.weight,
      stats: action.result.stats,
      baseExperience: action.result.base_experience,
      abilities: action.result.abilities,
      moves: action.result.moves,
      displayResult: true
   });
};

const resetBox = (state, action) => {
   return updateObject(state, {
      displayResult: false
   });
};

const fetchResultFailed = (state, action) => {
   return updateObject(state, { error: true });
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case actionTypes.SET_RESULT:
         return setResult(state, action);
      case actionTypes.FETCH_RESULT_FAILED:
         return fetchResultFailed(state, action);
      case actionTypes.RESET_BOX:
         return resetBox(state, action);
      default:
         return state;
   }
};

export default reducer;
```

actions.js

```
export const setResult = result => {
   return {
      type: actionTypes.SET_RESULT,
      result: result
   };
};

export const resetBox = () => {
   return {
      type: actionTypes.RESET_BOX
   };
};

export const fetchResultFailed = () => {
   return {
      type: actionTypes.FETCH_RESULT_FAILED
   };
};

export const nextResult = query => {
   return dispatch => {
      dispatch(resetBox());
      setTimeout(() => {
         dispatch(initResult(query));
      }, 100);
   };
};

export const initResult = query => {
   return dispatch => {
      axios
         .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${query}`)
         .then(response => {
            dispatch(setResult(response.data));
            console.log(response.data);
         })
         .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchResultFailed());
         });
   };
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, appreciate for the clear question, I leave an upvote.

Comment: Please have a look at this, might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092116/reacttransitiongroup-doesnt-works-with-react-redux-connected-component